# Are the results from persistent homology complete?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, data-analysis, topological-data-analysis

Do the homology groups for each Betti number as produced by persistent homology completely capture all the topological characteristics of the space? If not, what topological features are not captured?

I.e. will two topologically distinct spaces always have distinct persistent homology (e.g. barcodes or persistence diagrams) and will two topologically indistinguishable spaces always have identical results from persistent homology?

Comment: First of all, persistent homology is defined for metric spaces. It is not an invariant of topological spaces. Second, it is definitely very far from being a complete invariant. For example all the persistent homology for $\mathbb R^n$ (with, say, the Euclidean metric) is essentially trivial, but these spaces are not homeomorphic to each other.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip My feeling is that persistent homology is designed for finite metric spaces (at least, that is were people want to apply it). Do you know of any examples of two finite metric spaces that have the same barcodes, but are not isometric?

Comment: @Lorenzo: you can definitely cook up finite examples too. I think the following works. (ctd)

Comment: Let the first space have points $a,b,c,d$ where the distances between a,b and a,c are $1$. The distance between $a,c$ is $2$. Let the distance from $d$ to the three other points also be $2$. For the second space, let the distance between a,b and c,d be 1, and let the four distances a,c; a,d; b,c; b,d be $2$. Now the persistent homology in degree $0$ starts at rank 4, then jumps to rank $2$ at distance $1$, then jumps to rank $1$ at distance $2$. The components in each case are contractible, so the higher Betti numbers are all $0$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip thanks! For the first space, I think you meant that the distance from b to c is 2 (in the second sentence.) Very instructive examples. :)

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thank you for the explanation. So are there any guarantees for the kind of information that PH will give me for a given finite metric space?

Comment: @BrandonBrown: PH is a useful and powerful invariant, but there's no reason to expect it to classify metric spaces.